# Django Query, filter by user group

Tags: python, django

The below code returns a list of the users groups

```
admins = User.objects.all()
for i in admins:
 print i.groups.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
```

and i want to get all users that are in the group 'App_Admin', so i need something like the below, but obviously a query that works, the below churns out "invalid syntax"

```
admins = User.objects.filter(groups.all().values_list('name', flat=True)__in='App_Admin')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
admins = User.objects.filter(groups__name='App_Admin')
```

Comment: @Alasdair `groups` plural.